# SharePoint Server 2016 Mobile App

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, forms-authentication

I have a business requirement to allow SharePoint 2016 Site reachable from iOS/Android SharePoint Mobile Application.
I have setup a new Web App and extended and published it over the internet, I can open the Web Page just fine from any device including browsers in the mobile phone.
However, when I attempt to connect to the service via the Mobile App, I am able to authenticate using NTLM authentication, however all I see is a blank loading page.

Is there any recommended way to implement SharePoint Web App so it is useable from the mobile app? Also I have read that the application only supports NTLM and FBA authentication, have any of you tried to implement FBA with multifactor authentication and used it with the app?

Will be grateful for any response, thank you.

Comment: I want to confirm some information for further troubleshooting.

When it shows a blank loading page, which services do you want to connect to via the SharePoint Mobile App?

Comment: Just a plain Team Site Collection

Answer (score 0):

You can extend WebApp with FBA authentication. But in OOTB SharePoint have really simple implementation of SignIn and Identity pages, you can customize this pages or create a new identity pages. If you choose this way for authentication users you can configure Membership and Role Manager for example LdapMembership: Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapMembershipProvider - [Link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/configuring-sharepoint-2013-fba-with-secure-ldap/m-p/1149770) On my previous projects we used identity providers such as ADFS, [Okta](https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/DeploymentGuides/Sharepoint/Guide/deploy-sharepoint.htm) if you want more you can implement your custom identity provider and try cover really complex cases.

Comment: I have tried that as well, and have managed to also implement ADFS authentication. However my primary issue at hand currently is that even with basic NTLM authentication, the SharePoint Mobile application by Microsoft refuses to load the pages even after the authentication succeeds. Thank you for the FBA with LDAP idea, i'll look into that if i do succeed with making the application work.